# Chains for fixed gear bike noise problem

Tags: chain, fixed-gear, noise

I mounted my fixed gear bike and I would like your opinion about the installation of my chain.

The noise in the following video is made by my chain (and nothing else) and I am not reassured.
I first thought the run of the chain was not correct but yet it seems it does.
I checked that my chain can move vertically more than +/- 0.5 inch (halfway).

Here are my components (they are all new):

- Surly steamroller frame
- chain 1/2 x 1/8
- [miche Bottom bracket 107mm](https://www.probikeshop.fr/miche-boitier-axe-carre-primato-68xaa-7mm/90181.html?gshop=FR&ef_id=Cj0KCQjw9YWDBhDyARIsADt6sGbPfrHzMavcvdeNMh_cx10OaiDWAA_FoEuSTGWdw24OlybzIX58qfkaAtZZEALw_wcB:G:s&gclid=Cj0KCQjw9YWDBhDyARIsADt6sGbPfrHzMavcvdeNMh_cx10OaiDWAA_FoEuSTGWdw24OlybzIX58qfkaAtZZEALw_wcB)
- [miche primato adavanced drive](https://www.probikeshop.fr/miche-pedalier-primato-aa7-mm/90175.html?gshop=FR&ef_id=Cj0KCQjw9YWDBhDyARIsADt6sGb4xWN6vjOWtd3SPC8WHCOn8tM-juixYUlGNmI7ZsHKwThprPOF7AEaAmw9EALw_wcB:G:s&gclid=Cj0KCQjw9YWDBhDyARIsADt6sGb4xWN6vjOWtd3SPC8WHCOn8tM-juixYUlGNmI7ZsHKwThprPOF7AEaAmw9EALw_wcB)

Here is the [video](https://rpidejr.hopto.org/f/b9ff4c83c7524d23ae97/), how does it sound ?

Comment: Sounds about normal to me.

Comment: What's the cog?

Comment: @NathanKnutson : I don't have the precise model, it's a used cog that I bought in a shop. It's in steel and has 19t. Do you think it could lead do a misalignement of the chain ? How can I check that the tooth are still good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought the chain was rubbing on the wheel, if its a new chain then it might not have been greased. Don't use wd40 if its not greased, it will wear it faster. Try White Lightning.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your chain line?  Sometimes if your chain line is off you can hear the inside of the chain links rubbing a bit too much against the teeth on the cog and the chain ring.